# MVC4 Get user Tweets, alternative to v1 (deprecated)

Tags: twitter, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

Using `MVC4`, I would like to get the recent `Tweets` (3) of user's without having to request access from them, because that is a pain for the user. This is also because a user may be viewing another user and I would also like to display their Tweets.

This was fairly simple with `Twitter API v1`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=3&screen_name=' +   twitterUser,
   ...
});
```

..but its deprecated and will stop working in about two months from now.

I'm new to `Oauth` and have struggled to find any good material on how to get a user's Tweets, but I believe the process is a lot more complicated now with the `Twitter API v1.1`? Ideally, I'd like to achieve everthing in the front end, but think that I now need to do some authentication server side and will have to use `MVC`?

In order to get any user's `Tweets`, I was thinking that I could create a `Twitter` account for my application and use that to get anyone's Tweets, as long as they are not protected.

Does anyone know of any good libraries that I can use to achieve this, or is the out of the box `MVC4 Oauth` stuff alone enough to do the job?

Any suggestions of where to start, and especially examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [Linq2Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/), as this makes use of the `V1.1 API`.

An `MVCDemo` example of `Linq2Twitter` stores the authorised credentials in a `SessionStateCredentials` object, but I can store the object in cache and persist the authorisation for all users, meaning they won't have to authorise anything. Provided that a user's `Tweets` aren't protected, the `Tweet's` for any user should be retrievable this way.

Answer (score 0):

To use API 1.1, you have to have a Twitter account and a [Twitter application](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) and then [use OAUTH](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth) to authenticate your rate limited requests using [GET statuses/show/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid).  The only alternative I know is RSS which both Twitter & Facebook have kiiled, briught back and threatened to kill again:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name={USERNAME}
```

Comment: yep - but it works for now - like I said, can come down at anytime!  so they are really clamping down on alternatives.

Comment: I am looking for a solution using v1.1 though

Comment: OAUTH is baked into .net 4.5 (nuget for MVC4) - watch this video - http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates.  IF your Twitter application has access to the user's tweets, you are set, otherwise, the user will have to give permission to your application via OAUTH.

Comment: Yes I've seen the out of the box stuff. But I don't see why I can't set up an account with Twitter and use that to get anyone'e Tweets?